# How to click on the second instance of drop down box with similar html code - Selenium VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to download two xls files from two dropdown boxes which are located in two similar data boxes.
The first data box:

```
<div id="contain" style="height: 400px" data-highcharts-chart="2">
…several containers…
<g class="highcharts-exporting-group" data-z-index="3</g>
```

The full path:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/svg/g[6]
```

The second data box:

```
<div id="containB2C" style="height: 400px" data-highcharts-chart="3">
…several containers…
<g class="highcharts-exporting-group" data-z-index="3</g>
```

The full path:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/svg/g[6]
```

I can click the first dropdown box with the code:

```
obj.FindElementByClass("highcharts-exporting-group").Click
```

and select the item:

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='Download XLS']").Click
```

But I cannot click the second drop down box in the second data box with similar code. Would appreciate any tips on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As two dropdown boxes are similar, you could get a list or set of elements instead of a single element.

The below is just a demo and maybe has syntax error.(sorry I am not good at vba)

```vb
Dim titles As Object
Set titles = bot.findElementsByClass("highcharts-exporting-group")

For each item in titles
  item.Click
Next item
```

Comment: Please accept and up vote if it solves your problem, it will help others and myself in turn. If not working, let me know, I will try again.

Comment: Peter Quan, thank you for the tip. It drops down the second box but when I select 'Download XLS' with obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='Download XLS']").Click it gives me an run-time error 11 ElementNotVisibleError element not interactable though the element is visible.
When I stop the procedure and manually click on the drop-down item, then it works.